# Unviable bitwise OR assignment operator over object

Tags: c++

The following snippet (a simplification from real program) produces the following: `error: no viable overloaded '|='`

```
class CMyInt
{
  int mValue;

public:
  operator int() { return mValue; }

  void operator=(int &value) { mValue = value; }
};

template<class T>
class CBitFlags
{
  T mValue;

public:
  void SetFlag(int flag) { mValue |= flag; }
};

int main()
{
  CBitFlags<CMyInt> flags;
  flags.SetFlag(1);
}
```

Is there any straighforward way to solve it (if possible, with an additional operator as much) appart from these working alternatives, which I want to avoid?

- Changing `CMyInt::operator int()` to return by reference, after which the assignment part of `|=` at `CBitFlags` doesn't call my custom `CMyInt::operator=`, which I need called in the real program counterpart instead of "raw" assignment
- Changing bitwise OR assignment at `CBitFlags::SetFlag()` to `mValue = mValue | flag` (which I'm using for now)
- Implementing the `operator|=` at `CMyInt`

Note: the wrap-like aspect of the code can't be altered, i.e., don't get rid of `CMyInt` to use the `int` directly at `CBitFlags`.

EDIT: From first comments it seems there isn't any other way around it. But then, I would also like to know, why the longer OR assignment version works instead?

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with the alternatives?

Comment: I simply don't understand how you expect this to work without doing one of the things that you've listed.

Comment: @cigien The first alternative causes the assignment to be done at the POD type directly, while I need to execute extra code in `CMyInt` assignment operator. @cigied @paddy I don't understand why second alternative works when I've seen elsewhere that the shorthand `|=` version is "equivalent" to it. That's what motivated me to ask the question, so I can check if there's anything I'm missing since I would like to avoid that longer version even if it's acceptable.

Comment: `|` and `|=` are not exactly equivalent. The first can work on temporaries, but the second needs an l-value on the left hand side.

Comment: @cigien I get the sense, so I understand it just works that way and can't be overcomed with any slight variant of any assignment operator or such (at inner class, `CMyInt`). But judging from the different executions, don't you mean that "`|=` needs an implicit cast to a reference on the left hand side, while `|` doesn't necessarily look for it"? Since the shorthand version wants to modify the POD type directly. Otherwise I don't understand the concrete behaviour you expose.

Comment: Remove all the other stuff from the question, and leave basically the question in your last comment.

Answer (score 2):

On the template class **CBitFlags** you declare the method

```
void SetFlag(int flag) { mValue |= flag; }
```

that method expects an operator |= defined for the generic class T.

When you declare, in **main** method

```
CBitFlags<CMyInt> flags;
```

the compiler try to find a **|=** operator for class **CMyInt** that is not defined (you overloaded **=** operator instead **|=** operator) . What you should do is to change the operator definition on **CMyInt** as follows:

```
void operator|=(int &value) { mValue = value; }
```

to avoid **"error: no viable overloaded '|='"**